# Increase correlation of whole set part by part

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have data-set of $n$ elements (pixels) with three attributes $A$, $B$ and $C$ where strong  correlation exists between attributes $A$ and other two attributes $B$ and $C$ and correlation between $A$ and $B$ is stronger than the one between $A$ and $C$ attributes. Each element has all attributes (no NAs) and attributes are independent. I'm trying to modify values of attributes $C$ in order to boost its correlation and to achieve $cor(A,C)>cor(A,B)$

My idea is that if I randomly split data-set to $k$ non-overlapping parts and to calculate $cor(A,B)_k$ and $cor(A,C)_k$. Then I try to modify values of attribute $C_k$ until I achieve that $cor(A,C)_k>cor(A,B)_k$. My hypothesis is that if I achieve independently that for each part $k$ $cor(A,C)_k>cor(A,B)_k$ that in the end I will have that correlation on the whole set is also greater $cor(A,C)>cor(A,B)$. I don't want to temper with the way of calculating correlation in order to artificially boost it, I just use it as a measure of how well I have modeled attributes $B$ and $C$. My problem is that my statistics background is poor and I'm not sure if this is possible or should I include some additional conditions for each $k$ part, in order to achieve greater correlation over the whole data-set.

I'm working with some rasters and I have successfully programmed this through R, but since I'm getting bad results I'm not sure if I made some mistake while coding or my starting premise is wrong.

**EDIT 2**

For those who are more into remote sensing, here is the explanation of $A$, $B$ and $C$ attributes and idea behind proposed method:

Attribute $A$ is surface soil moisture (*SSM*) and attributes $B$ and $C$ is temperature vegetation dryness indexes (*TVDI*) calculated in two different ways. Without getting into details, *SSM* and *TVDI* are calculated from different remote sensing sources, but there exists strong correlation between these two.

*TVDI* is usually determined globally using same parameters for whole area of interest (attribute $B$). But my point is that if area of interest is very large (like the whole continent or whole world), it might be better to divide area to smaller parts and locally calculate *TVDI* for each part and then merge it all back to one raster.

I'm trying to develop new method (attribute $C$) where *TVDI* is calculated with local parameters, using moving kernel (for an example kernel with center of 100x100 pixels with buffer of 50 pixels, [similar to focal raster operations](https://gisgeography.com/map-algebra-global-zonal-focal-local/)). So when kernel is positioned at some part of raster matrix, I use all data that falls inside the kernel+buffer (in an example that is 150x150 pixels) and I calculate *TVDI* just for the central part of the kernel. The second part of the idea is that I increase size of buffer gradually (which after enough iteration actually covers whole area of interest) and to use the correlation as a measure of what is the best buffer size. In the meantime I consulted with some of my colleagues, so maybe correlation is not the best way of determining the best buffer size, but I didn't get any better results using RMSE either.

Whatever I do, the measurement of how well I have modeled both global and local *TVDI* is correlation calculated for the whole area of interest. Basically, I'm calculating correlation of corresponding pixels of *SSM* raster, global *TVDI* and the local *TVDI* which represents all center parts of kernels merged back to one large raster.

So I'm getting that independently, each 100x100 pixels center of locally calculated *TVDI* has greater correlation with *SSM* than the corresponding 100x100 part of global *TVDI*, but when I merge all local *TVDI* into one large raster and then calculate correlation, it is way smaller than the one for global *TVDI*.

I don't know how is it possible that correlation is stronger part by part, but when I merge all parts into one, correlation gets lower.

This is the basic problem, I need someone to explain me if this is statistically okay and what I need to achieve for each part that in the end will get me the increase of correlation over the whole set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. You write " I'm trying to modify attributes C in order to boost its correlation". But you do not explain what modifications are permitted. E.g. why can't you set simply C equal to A which makes sure that the correlation between A and C is maximal?

Comment: @g g Sorry for misunderstanding, I tried to make problem more mathematical. I have added explanations of attributes.
What I tried to explain without getting into how to modify attribute $C$, if each part ($cor(A,C)_k>cor(A,B)_k$ has greater correlation, is correlation calculated for the whole set of $A$ and $B$ attributes also going to be greater $cor(A,C)_{whole_set}>cor(A,B)_{whole_set} or some additional conditions must be honored?

Comment: The exact correlation structure of your experiment is still not clear to me. On the one hand you write: "where strong correlation exists between attributes A and other two attributes B and C" on the other you write "attributes are independent". which seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: Furthermore, there seems to be more structure in your measurement, because you have "locally" and "globally" calculated TVDI and you talk about a moving kernel. Maybe a start would be to describe in detail how your experiments differ from taking iid samples of a trivariate random variable with marginal attributes A, B and C.

Comment: Regarding the independent attributes, I meant to say that they have been derived independently using different methods.

Comment: I have added additional explanations of proposed method after **EDIT 2**, thank you again for taking part in solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have two objections to your proposed procedure. First, if A and C are barely correlated, I don't see a legitimate way to find subsets that behave as you wish. Second,
I don't see how you could expect A and C 'micromanaged' in this way would reliably have a higher correlation in future studies (by you or others).

There are various ways to 'tamper' with data to get give
the (usually false) impression of a higher then natural correlation. Consider independent data vectors $A$ and $C$ below.

Initially, variables $A$ and $C$ happen to have modest (but insignificant) *negative* correlation. Then I throw away almost half of the
observations, which are relatively far away from
the 45-degree line, getting a much higher
correlation $(r \approx 0.67)$ between the remaining points $A_1$ and
$C_1.$ (You may think I'm joking, but I once
refereed a paper that tried this. I was suspicious that the edges of the submitted data cloud looked 'too flat'.)

This method will work most of the time. Maybe I misunderstood something and your method is OK.
But can you explain how it is OK and mine is not?

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2));  set.seed(2019)
A = rnorm(200, 100, 15); C = rnorm(200, 100, 15)
cor(A,C)
[1] -0.02522233
plot(A,C, pch=20)
 abline(15,1, col="red"); abline(-15,1, col="red")
cond = (C>=A-15 & C<=A+15)
mean(cond)
[1] 0.53

A1 = A[cond]; C1 = C[cond] 
cor(A1, C1)
[1] 0.6702914
plot(A1, C1, pch=20)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for taking part in solving my problem. I have added some additional explanations in question (between *start of EDIT* and *end of EDIT*). I don't try to artificially boost correlation, I'm only using it as a measure "how well" I have calculated attributes $B$ and $C$